# Google spreadsheet CTRL+Shift+E

Tags: google-sheets

I have spreadsheet with two sheets: `current_sheet` and `archive_sheet`.

I also have a script (which I created) which removes data from `current_sheet` and appends it to `archive_sheet` once per month.

The sheets have an `arrayFormula`, and after every monthly move operation, cells with this `arrayFormula` wind up without any results - and I receive a warning message, indicating that I should press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in order to resolve the problem.

Once I've done so - the formulas work again. What I'm wondering is... *how can I alter my script so that I don't have to provide this manual fix every month?*

Answer (score 0):

use a time driven trigger to run your script each month

Comment: I already use time driven trigger for moving data every month. But after every monthly move operation by my trigger, I have problem in my sheet with ArrayFormula that I described in post.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using script to move your data each month, try copying the values, then clearing the original data and reinitialise the formula.  Without seeing your formula and have a clear understanding of what your doing, im kinda punching in the dark.