# refresh cell instead of pressing ctrl-Shift-E manually

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a few queries on the sheet where I extract info to a database.

The problem I have is that the code implemented was fine till some sheets won't display the query showing the: "warning: one or more of these results' entries may not be displayed. Select ctrl+Shift+E to show them.

I tried clearing the values and pasting them back to no avail.

what else can I do?

Comment: What problem are you concerned about? Is it the need to force a refresh so you can see the values in the browser? Or are you having problems with scripts reading the ranges containing the queries?

Comment: to force the refresh! The scrip is fine. Just when I fire the script to transfer da data to my database, is not there cause it force me to do it manually with the key combination

Comment: Does the script experience any errors on the 'missing data'? If so, what error or response do you see?

Comment: No errors. Is just a simple query: =IFERROR(QUERY(sheet1!A3:D41;"SELECT A,B,C WHERE C <>'' ",),"")

Comment: from that query I collect data. it can me any number of rows collected. The query works fine. Just that I have to go and force it pressing ctrl+Shift+E for the query to return the values

Comment: There's not much to that query, but if you have lots of other intensive functions in your sheet it could be that the sheet is taking too long to process them, and stops auto-recalculating. (Do you see error messages saying "Some functions are taking a long time..."?) You referred to "code", but have given an example of a spreadsheet function - do you have any google-apps-script functions on this spreadsheet?

Comment: you're right. I said "script" instead of function. I apologize.

Comment: is not function intense. and it does not take long to process. I do have lot of code on the script but no custom functions working on the worksheet

Comment: I was thinking on trying to get rid of the IFERROR maybe it help. What do you think?

Comment: I've seen this problem pop up where I've been using appendRow with the data in the wrong format. If you're using a script to copy the result of the query, the problem could be there. Can you post the relevant section of your script?

Comment: @Mogsdad. I have the same problem. And I see this question on stackoverflow without answers. Basically if you have a function that has "=CONTINUE()" that fills the other cells, when you run a script like a sort or something, those CONTINUE() functions are jumbled and you need to press ctrl+shift+E manually to fix it.

Comment: it seems like alot of people are having the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061428/google-spreadsheet-ctrlshifte I don't have enough points, but someone should start a bounty on this one. I'm willing to contribute what ever i can.

Comment: Can someone share a doc with a query() and the issue?

Answer (score 6):

IMHO I don't think that there is a canonical answer to this question - there has always been a loud clamour from users around certain topics which merely dissipate into an eerie silence of the Google docs engineering team (this issue seems to be shrouded in the same eternal mystery as IMPORTRANGE frequently failing or SPLIT not creating a perfect matrix).

I have been bitten by this myself several times so have some experience. I have used a heath-robinson workaround, which has worked for me.  But YMMV.

The OP's question discusses the situation where there is a formula which was working well, but after some time of operation, a Ctrl+Shift+E situation has started to occur.

(There are other situations where Ctrl+Shift+E might occur due to results of one formula attempting to overwrite onto cells written by another formula.  In this scenario, sometimes adding EXPAND at the beginning of the desired formula does the trick.  Also using Filter functions, rather than 'IF' comparisons, does mop-up previous =CONTINUE(1,2,3) cells  ... but perhaps neither of these are likely to be of help to the OPs question).

In my experience the spreadsheet might develop such a 'confused' behaviour over time, so requiring Ctrl+Shift+E, meaning a period of time where there are  several uses-of-the-spreadsheet resulting in changes to the data. I might further speculate that there is more likelihood of this confused behaviour when the referred-to data is more dynamic e.g. rows added, rows removed OR that there are other formulas which also calculate from the same data set (let alone that these two formulas relate to each other).

I think that the idiom 'confused-behaviour' is appropriate since the actual engineering of the spreadsheet is an open box only to google engineers; we cannot rationalise its workings. So it seems mysterious and magical how, in the OP's case and my experience, the spreadsheet was working well, but then altered behaviour to require Ctrl+Shift+E without there being any change in the formulas, only in the sheets' accumulated data changes through usage.

I am giving an example of my workaround using an example case of mine. Note that in my case the data and also the problematic formulas are in one single sheet which I am calling the production sheet

The workaround involves using a script to duplicate a 'template-sheet', in the same spreadsheet as the production sheet.  The template-sheet is structurally identical to the production sheet with the same column headings, but with only a few lines of sample data. It has the same formulas as the production sheet, which refer to the sample data in the self-same template sheet (not to the production sheet). Importantly, the template sheet is not showing 'confused-behaviour' - no Ctrl+Shift+E is required in the formula cells should there be any changes to the template's sample data.  It also contains the formating of the production sheet.

So, when the script runs, it creates a duplicate of the template-sheet; it subsequently copies over the production sheet's data  to this template duplicate and reapplies the formats. This duplicate becomes the new production sheet. The old production sheet is hidden (in my case, but could be deleted).

I have this system operational on a Tasks List spreadsheet being used by 12 people daily, where Tasks come in by google form throughout the day (and are themselves copied over to the production sheet by another script, not shown as not relevant to this OP). Once a task is  completed, the task's row is removed from the production sheet. So the data grows and shrinks constantly throughout the day. The duplicate sheet is created each night, by timed trigger upon the insertSheet() function.  Here is the script I use:

```
function insertSheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet =ss.getSheets()[0]; //first sheet is the production sheet
  var sheetRange = sheet.getRange('A3:P');
  var sheetValues= sheetRange.getValues();
  var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getTimeZone(), 'ddMMMyyyy-hh:mm:ss');
  var ex = sheet.setName('CCEs' + d);
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('templateSheet');
  var s2 = ss.insertSheet(0,{template: templateSheet});
  var height = sheetRange.getHeight();
  s2.insertRowsAfter(2, height)
  s2.setName('CCEs');
  templateSheet.hideSheet();
  ex.hideSheet();
  s2.getRange('A3:P' + (sheetValues.length+2)).setValues(sheetValues);
  format(); //
  templateSheet.hideSheet();
  ex.hideSheet();
}

function format(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formatRange = ss.getSheetByName('templateSheet').getRange('B2:N2').copyTo(ss.getSheetByName('CCEs').getRange(2,2, ss.getSheetByName('CCEs').getMaxRows() -1,14), {formatOnly:true});
}
```

Prior to deploying this strategy, the spreadsheet would experience 'confused-behaviour' after a couple of days or so.

The sheet contained three formulas which would become confused.  They are not important to the OP, but I duplicate here just to give the reader a feeling for the success of this strategy:

```
=arrayformula(IFERROR(FILTER(if(row(O:O) =1,"Auto Time Stamp ",iferror(1/0)) &O:O&if(row(O:O) =1,"copy",),len(A:A)),"Error"))

=Arrayformula(iferror(if(filter(L:L, len(A:A)) - filter(A:A, len(A:A))>0, if( int(filter(L:L, len(A:A)) - filter(A:A, len(A:A))) = 0 , text( text(filter(L:L, len(A:A)), "HH:mm") -text(filter(A:A, len(A:A)), "HH:mm") , "H:mm") , int(filter(L:L, len(A:A)) - filter(A:A, len(A:A))) & "Day(s), " & text( text(filter(L:L, len(A:A)), "HH:mm") -text(filter(A:A, len(A:A)), "HH:mm") , "H:mm") ) ,iferror(1/0)),"Time Taken"))

=arrayformula( IFERROR(if((ISBLANK(FILTER(J1:J,LEN(A1:A))) * (FILTER(G1:G,LEN(A1:A)) = "Normal")* (now()-FILTER(A1:A,LEN(A1:A))> OverdueTimings!A1 )),"OVERDUE Normal", if((ISBLANK(FILTER(J1:J,LEN(A1:A))) * (FILTER(G1:G,LEN(A1:A)) = "Urgent")* (now()-FILTER(A1:A,LEN(A1:A))> OverdueTimings!A2 )),"OVERDUE Urgent", if((ISBLANK(FILTER(J1:J,LEN(A1:A))) * (FILTER(G1:G,LEN(A1:A)) = "Very Urgent")* (now()-FILTER(A1:A,LEN(A1:A))> OverdueTimings!A3 )),"OVERDUE V. Urgent", IFERROR(1/0)))),countif(if((ISBLANK(FILTER(J1:J,LEN(A1:A))) * (FILTER(G1:G,LEN(A1:A)) = "Normal")* (now()-FILTER(A1:A,LEN(A1:A))> OverdueTimings!A1 )),"OVERDUE Normal", if((ISBLANK(FILTER(J1:J,LEN(A1:A))) * (FILTER(G1:G,LEN(A1:A)) = "Urgent")* (now()-FILTER(A1:A,LEN(A1:A))> OverdueTimings!A2 )),"OVERDUE Urgent", if((ISBLANK(FILTER(J1:J,LEN(A1:A))) * (FILTER(G1:G,LEN(A1:A)) = "Very Urgent")* (now()-FILTER(A1:A,LEN(A1:A))> OverdueTimings!A3 )),"OVERDUE V. Urgent", iferror(1/0)))),"OVERDUE *")& " OVERDUE"))
```

After several days, we delete all the accumulated old production sheets.